# Dockerfile from ubuntu:22.04 apt unable to locate package python3

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, apt

When I `docker build` this:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get install -y python3
```

I get

```
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:22.04
 ---> c6b84b685f35
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get install -y python3
 ---> Running in d1f4eff8d024
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package python3
```

What's wrong?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/378558/160225

Comment: You need to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...` in the same command.  The base `ubuntu` image doesn't have a downloaded package index, and it changes fairly frequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run `apt-get upgrade` then you can install `python` packages.

Here is an example:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y python3
```

PS:

i don't know about you motivation to use Ubuntu image but may you consider about use [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) image